# How to do empty list check in maximo anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am getting few json response from service as "-@@EmptyComplexField@@-". Due to which screen crashes. How to do a proper empty check for complex feild in maximo anywhere. Please help with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

We can do a empty check for list as below
if(list && list!="-@@EmptyComplexField@@-")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting this EmptyComplexField string down at your layer.  Are you sure you've defined your multiplicity correctly on the OSLC Resources app for these new children objects?

```
if (/-or-many$/.test(complexAttribute.multiplicity)){
                var attributeName = complexAttribute.remoteName;
                if (!(attributeName in data)){
```

Are you making sure these complexattributes are set as requiredattributes on the view before you display it?

Comment: Yes, I am adding OSLC resource in required attributes of the view

Answer (score 0):

The most correct answer would be:

```
if (list && list != PlatformConstants.EMPTY_COMPLEX_FIELD) { ... }
```